# Warum "Niederlande" statt "Niederlände"?

Tags: spelling, grammatical-number

Das Plural von “das Land” ist “die Länder”.  "Die Niederlande" sind immer Plural, doch wird nicht als "Die Niederlände" geschrieben.  Warum nicht?

Ich habe das immer falsch geschrieben.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Es gibt eine Reihe von Substantiven, die zwei verschiedene Pluralformen haben. Das Wort *»das Land«* ist eines davon.

- **das Wort**

  - *die Wörter* (wenn sie gemeinsam keine Idee transportieren)
  - *die Worte* (transportieren gemeinsam eine Bedeutung)
- **das Tuch**

  - *die Tücher* (kleine rechteckige gebrauchsfertige Textilien)
  - *die Tuche* (Rohware, aus der Kleidung geschneidert wird)
- **der Mann**

  - *die Männer* (wenn sie keine Gruppe bilden)
  - *die Mannen*, auch *die Mann* (wenn sie etwas gemeinsam haben, Phrase *»alle Mann an Bord«*)
- **das Land**

  - *die Länder* (streng abgegrenzte politische Regionen)
  - *die Lande* (Gegenden, Landstriche)

und viele andere.

Die Niederlande waren ursprünglich die sehr flachen küstennahen Gegenden.

Es gibt auch die Phrase: »durch die Lande ziehen«, sie bedeutet: »wandern«

Comment: Ich frage mich gerade, ob ***die Wasser*** auch dazugehört (vs. ***die Wässer***)

Comment: Was auffällt, ist, dass es immer Wörter (!) sind, deren gewöhnlicher Plural mit Umlaut gebildet wird: Tuch-Tücher-Tuche, Mann-Männer-Mannen, Land-Länder-Lande, Wasser-Wässer-Wasser, Mund-Münder-Munde. Und könnte man das dann noch produktiv einsetzen: Haus-Häuser-Hause? Maus-Mäuse-Mausen? Und was ist mit den Blagen? Zurückführbar auf Blage-Bläger-Blagen? Oder kommt letzteres von Balg-Bälger-Blagen?

Comment: Ja. Auch *das Mal* (Die Male, die (Denk-)Mäler), die *Brust* (die Brüste, die (Arm-)Bruste), das *Ding* (Dinger, Dinge). Zu einer anderen Gruppe gehören aber Mutter (Mütter - Muttern), Bank (Banken, Bänke), Strauß (Strauße, Sträuße), weil hier schon die Singularformen unterschiedliche Dinge bedeuten.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Das wäre eigentlich eine eigene Frage wert.

Comment: Zur Frage der Herkunft dieser Formen: Für die Neutra kannte das Mittelhochdeutsche offenbar zwei starke Deklinationen, eine ohne Umlaut und Plural auf -e und eine mit Umlaut und Plural auf -er. *Land* konnte anscheinend nach beiden Schemata dekliniert werden. Welcher Deklination althochdeutsch *lant* (Vorläufer von *Land*) angehört, habe ich noch nicht rauskriegen könne.ń.

Answer (score 8):

"Lande" ist ein alter Plural von "Land". <sup>1</sup>

Verwandte Ausdrücke:

> Es ging eine Mär durch die Lande...
>
> Er zog durch die Lande und wurde mit allerlei Künsten und Fertigkeiten bekannt.

Man trifft so etwas vor allem in älteren Texten. Märchen wären ein guter Platz, danach zu suchen.

Die Bedeutung von "Lande" scheint dabei oft eher in Richtung "Landschaften", "Landstriche" zu gehen, weniger in Richtung "Staaten"; vielleicht weil (das ist jetzt meine Privathypothese) die Idee von Staaten (mit festen Grenzen etc.) sich später herausgeformt hat als das Wort. Der deutschsprachige Raum war ja über Jahrhunderte ein Fleckenteppich kleiner und kleinster Herrschaften, da übertrat man praktisch alle Nas' lang eine "Staatsgrenze" (nach heutigen Verständnis), ohne es eigentlich zu merken. Insofern waren Landschaftsformen den Leuten sicherlich bewusster als *Länder*grenzen.

> Die Sache war in aller Munde

Ebenfalls eine seltene, alte Pluralform ("in aller Leute Münder"), die man eigentlich nur noch in dieser Redewendung findet.

Und natürlich:

> Seine Worte hinterließen bleibenden Eindruck, obwohl die einzelnen Wörter eher einfacher Art waren.

Synthese:

> Des Philosophen goldene **Worte** waren in aller **Munde**. Sogar die **Rosse** wieherten sie durch die **Lande**, und seine **Mannen** riefen sie in die **Gemache**.

Bisher nicht besprochene:

- Gemach - Gemächer - Gemache
- Ross - Rösser - Rosse
- Wasser - Wässer - Wasser

---

<sup>1</sup> Schönen Gruß, Björn!

Comment: Gruß zurück ;-)

Comment: Schöne Antwort und upvoted. Aber ist „in aller Munde“ wirklich ein Plural, oder ist es „im Munde aller“ umgestellt? Das „in/im“ wäre ja nachvollziehbar, analog zu „in Herberts Rucksack“ aber „im Rucksack Herberts“.

Comment: Wenn ich mir den Dativ Plural dieser Formen ansehe (in Landen, Worten, Mannen, Tuchen), bin ich doch sehr sicher, daß es sich bei „in aller Munde“ um die regelhaft umgestellte Form von „Im Munde aller“ handelt.

Comment: @Ludi  Ja, habe ich mir auch überlegt. Ich weiß es nicht. Jedenfalls passt "Munde" als (hypothetische) Pluralform in die Reihe der Wörter elementarer Begriffe, die sonst Umlautpluralformen haben. Vielleicht ein Indiz, der für meine These spricht: Wenn es Dativ Singular wäre, sollte parallel zu "in aller Munde" auch "in aller Mund" verbreitet sein, und das ist es eindeutig nicht.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann guter Hinweis! Allerdings bin ich mir da nicht ganz sicher. Ich denke, wenn solche Fügungen erstarren, können sie sehr dominant werden. Vergleiche „auf Seiten“. Ich würde jedenfalls nicht sagen „er kämpfte auf Seite des Gegners“.

Comment: @Ludi Da bin ich ganz auf deiner Seite. (Vielleicht auch auf deiner Seiten und auf deinen Seiten.)